# How to display sonar readings in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, sonar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom robot and have a URDF model of it set up in rviz. I have several Sonars and Sharp IR sensors mounted on it. I'm working my way toward using the navigation tools, how do I show my sensor readings in Rviz? Or am I heading in the wrong direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10172/how-to-display-sonar-readings-in-rviz/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-06-07**:
So I've requested a new plugin in RVIZ!  https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4996  Hopefully this will be resolved soon.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Officially merged as sensor_msgs/Range with RVIZ Plugin: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Range

---

Old answer:

Hi, in order to display sonars in RVIZ, you could modify the nxt_rviz_plugin on your own or use the one we've already modified.  Our repository is ([https://github.com/cwru-robotics/smart_wheelchair](http://https://github.com/cwru-robotics/smart_wheelchair)) and the relevant package is range_rviz_plugin.  An example view of this plugin is available [here on my youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rIAGKA6uS8).

If you download the range_rviz_plugin and then `rosmake range_rviz_plugin`, it will be available in RVIZ under "Plugins -> Manage" and then make sure it's selected.  It should then be available in the normal way "Add" -> "New Display", etc.

The way we've designed the plugin to work, you should publish [sensor_msgs/Range](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html) messages on a common topic for each division you care about.  For instance, I read all of my sonars in serial order to minimize read errors and publish each of these on /sonars.  The way I tell the sonars apart is through the transform frame_ids, and I rely on [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) to transform the range data for my other nodes.  I have 6 sonars, so I set Buffer Length to 6 so that each of my sonars is always visible.

I would recommend you publish your sonars on one topic and then at least one other topic for your IR rangers.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kartik Paigwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35871/kartik-paigwar/) on 2018-06-14**:
The github link is not active, can you repost the link please

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2018-06-14**:
I updated the answer, but look here:
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Range

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The NXT stack contains a plugin to display sonar messages in rviz. The sonar readings get displayed as a cone. See [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_rviz_plugin) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just now committed a "Range" display to rviz.  It is currently in trunk.  In a few days we'll probably have a debian in ros-unstable, and when Electric releases, this should be included.

Thanks to Chad Rockey and Melonee Wise for the range display code.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2